# How to stress test ext3 partition on android?

Tags: android, linux, filesystems, stress-testing, ext3

I've had several errors in kernel logs on device boot after all partitions were mounted.

```
ext3_free_blocks_sb: bit already cleared for block ######
```

After searching I've discovered that a [bugfix](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=commit;h=f25f624263445785b94f39739a6339ba9ed3275d) for the same issue was already integrated in the kernel.

Then I've searched for similar commits on repository and didn't find anything so it seems like the bug was fixed on the mainstream and the issue is Android-related.

From the [discussion](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=494927#c17) on RedHat bugtracker about the bug I discovered that it can be reproduced with stress-test utility. Unfortunately, I don't know any of these for `ext3` on Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difficulty with porting such diagnostic tools to Android is it's reduced kernel functionallity. In this case there is a bunch of filesystem stress utilities for regular linux:

- [`Bonnie++`](http://www.coker.com.au/bonnie++/)
- [`dbench`](http://samba.org/ftp/tridge/dbench/)
- `fsstress` and other tools included in [LTP](http://ltp.sourceforge.net/)
- etc.

Most of them require specific headers or `BASH` script features which are missing in Android.

After rewiewing available set of tools in filesystem test case of LTP I came up with the following approach:

1. Find a tool with minimal subset of scripts, headers and syscalls.
2. Compile it using Android NDK.
3. Install [`BASH` for Android](https://github.com/grantland/android-bash) to run required scripts.
4. Replace missing commands with their' [Busybox](http://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html) equivalents.

Comment: If you're having trouble with not getting any views, try editing your post. Tell the community where you're at with your project. Prove to them that you're actively working on it. These edits will also bump your post onto the front page, which will give you the views you want. And who knows, you may get lucky and the expert on your question may drop by.